# Mixing entity models and viewmodels in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

As I am beginning to understand, in MVC it's all about viewmodels to display data in the views. But when the Index-method in my home controller looks like this;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Products.ToListAsync());
}
```

how can I then insert a partial view with a viewmodel in my web page, like this (_Layout.cshtml):

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Partial("_ShoppingCart.cshtml")
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

After all, the index-method needs an entity model. If I try to pass a viewmodel to the index view, I get an exception telling me that the model is not found in the _context.

Comment: unrelated nitpick, I'd recommend using `ToList()` instead of `ToListAsync` for what you're doing.  I've found cases where `ToListAsync` is dramatically slower, and the way you're using it might as well be synchronous in the first place.

Comment: You can use `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns a partial view based on a view model (and the `Index()` does not need an entity model (that should also be using a view model)

Answer (score 1):

You might already know that why ViewModels should be used in your view and why not entities but if you don't then let me explain this.

When you are displaying data on the page, you usually need properties like `ItemSelected` or `HideItem` i.e. Anything which is only relevant to the page and won't be needed on your `entities`.

So now we know the importance of why we need to keep `entities` and `viewmodels`. Now the question is how do you shift data

`from entities to viewmodels when displaying data`

OR

`from viewmodels to entities when updating data on db`

You have two options

- Either write your own mapping logic which does the conversion.
- Use Automapper (http://automapper.org/) which do the job for you with minimal effort from your side.

If you are thinking about using AutoMapper then also have a look at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6 which is specifically for Entity Framework

Comment: What does Microsoft suggest to be done in this situation? I'm sure they didn't make such a complex and robust framework (that is Asp.Net Core) just to be dependent on third party plugins?

Comment: asp.net core is a modular framework and there are more than one way to skin a cat using this framework. This is more relevant to the learning curve. Not everyone face this problem because they might architect their application differently. But this is a common issue for people who starts learning MVC or any experienced developer who prefers MVC over web api, angularjs, web sockets or grpc and etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use use the child action method here

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutHome.cshtml";
}

@Html.Action("HomeSection")

@Html.Action("AboutSection")
```

as you can see this index page dose'nt have any model assigned to it now checking Homesection action looks looks like this

```
  [ChildActionOnly]
        public async Task<ActionResult> HomeSection()
        {
            try
            {
                Home home = new Home();
                home = await HomePageBLL.GetHomeSection();
                return View("_HomeSectionPartial", home);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

and _HomeSectionPartial view looks like this

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@model  NSDataComponent.Home
<section id="home" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20">
```

this is an optimal idea to use when you want to use different partial views with different models to be rendered in the same main view note that even main view can have a model base